# Настройка ключей SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-key

Добрый день, настраивал сервер по статье https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/c-ubuntu-14-04-ru

Не смог настроить доступ по ключу. Могу заходить с машин, у которых нет ключа. То есть авторизация по ключу не сработала. Как определить, на каком этапе я ошибся?

Comment: плюс ко всему, добавил пользователя и добавил его в группу sudo командой и вывалилось сообщение о точ что юхер добавлен Adding user rusa to group sudo.
Но начинаю ставить что-то от пользователя
sudo apt-get install - выдает ошибку 
-bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал пересоздать пользователя, внимательно читая статью...

Answer (score 1):

Ошибиться Вы могли в разных местах. Чтобы начать отладку, запустите подключение по ssh с дополнительным ключом -vvv. Это включит вывод отладочных сообщений на клиенте - они помогут понять, почему происходит не то, что Вы хотели, и что же происходит на самом деле.

Answer (score 0):

Создаём ключ:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024 -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Копируем ключи на удаленный компьютер, к которому будем подключаться по ключам:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub USERNAME@192.168.0.10
```

где USERNAME - имя пользователя, под которым будем в дальнейшем подключаться по ключу.

Проверьте, есть ли ваш пользователь в группе `sudo`:

```
cat /etc/group | grep sudo
```

Проверьте, установлен ли у вас пакет `sudo`:

```
aptitude search sudo
which sudo
```

Comment: Сделал как вы описали, как проверить что ключ работает, у меня по прежнему спрашивает пароль при входе

Comment: Ключ получается не сработал, так как могу через мобильник зайти на сервер

Comment: Вообще мне кажетс, что я жду иного результата. Что я ожидаю, что сделав ключи я смогу заходить только с компа, на котором есть секретный ключ, и не важно ввел я пароль или нет. Что выходит на практике: С компа, на котором есть ключ я захожу без пароля, но с других компов я могу зайти с паролем. Я всегда думал, что ключи это дополнительная защита над паролем. Т.е пользователь заходит, набирает пароль , если пароль верный, то идет сравнение ключей и если есть на локальном компе ключ, то пускает, если ключа нет, то не важно правильный или неправильный пароль ввел пользователь

Comment: Вам надо отключить возможность входа под паролем, для этого в файле `sshd_config` добавьте строки `PasswordAuthentication no` и
`ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` и перезапустите `sshd`. После этого вы сможете попасть на сервер только с компьютера(ов), где есть ключи.

Comment: А под root тоже нельзя будет зайти с паролем?

Comment: Под root тоже. Но в Ubuntu по-умолчанию отключена возможность логина под root'ом.

Comment: я на сервер захожу под root

Comment: В целях безопасности лучше заходить под пользователем, а команды, требующие привилегий, запускать через `sudo`. Либо, если сильно хочется работать под рутом, уже после логина под пользователем набирать `sudo su`.